# Отрегулировать длину выпадающего списка select

Tags: html, select

Есть select:

```
<select id="age" >
     <option>1</option>
      ....
    <option>90</option>
    </select>
```

Само собой, выпадающий список получаются дюже длинным. Как задать его размер на 5-6 элементов списка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное, что пришло в голову :)

Там где события **onclick** и **onmouseleave** меняй цифру **5** - это и будет его размер :)

```
<select size="1" position="absolute" onclick="size=(size!=1)?n:5;" onmouseleave="size=(size!=5)?n:1;"> 
    <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
    <option selected value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
    <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
    <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
    <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
    <option selected value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
    <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
    <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
    <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
    <option selected value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
    <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
    <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
    <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
    <option selected value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
    <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
    <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
</select>
```